# Easy way to handle nested transactions

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Suppose there is an "addUser" function, inside we need to insert a record to "Account" table and "User" table, so the two steps have to be within a transaction too, so we will write the following code:

```
function addUser (userName, password) {
    sequelize.transaction(function () {
        return AccountModel.create(...)
        .then(UserModel.create(...))    
    })
}
```

However, in another "addTeam" function, inside we need to insert a record to "Team" table and create a admin user using the above function. The function also need to be wrapped inside a transaction.

So the problem comes, the "addUser" function sometimes need to begin a new transaction, and sometimes need to use the transaction passed in. The most obvious ways is below:

```
function addUser (userName, password, transaction) {
       let func = function (t) {
           return  AccountModel.create(..., t)
           .then(()=>UserModel.create(..., t)));
       if (transaction) func(t);
       else sequelize.transaction(x=>func(t));
}

function addTeam() {
     sequelize.transaction(x=> {
         TeamModel.create(..., x)
         .then(y=>addUser(x));
     });
}
```

Obviously, it is awful. How to deal with it easily, which let transaction totally transparent to the caller like below:

```
@Transaction
async function addUser(userName, password) {
    await AccountModel.create(...);
    await UserModel.create(...);
}

@Transaction
async function addTeam(...) {
    await TeamModel.create(...);
    await addUser(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, and feel great.

I used the CLS feature sequelize provides, like the code below:

```
let namespace = Sequelize.cls = cls.createNamespace('myschool');
export const db = new Sequelize(config.db.url);

export const trans = option => operation => async function () {
    let t = namespace.get('transaction');
    let hasTrans = !!t;
    t = t  || await db.transaction();
    try {
        let result = await operation.apply(null, arguments);
        if (!hasTrans) await t.commit();
        return result;
    }
    catch (e) {
        if (!hasTrans) await t.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
};
```

The above code just create a transaction and commit it if there is no transaction in the local context, otherwise just leave it.

And each business function want a transaction just need to use the above high order function to wrap like below:

```
export const createSchool = trans()( async (name, accountProps) => {
    let school = await SchoolModel.create({name});
    let teacher = await createTeacher({...accountProps, schoolId: school.get('id')});
    return {school, teacher};
});
```

Comment: There is a discussion in v5.x to remove cls: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10819

Answer (score 7):

`sequelize.transaction` accepts an options object - If `options.transaction` is set, this will create a savepoint in the transaction (provided that the SQL dialects supports it), otherwise it will create a new transaction

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#transactionoptions-promise

So you should be able to do simply

```
sequelize.transaction({ transaction }, x=>func(t));
```

Comment: I actually want the transaction to be transparent to the caller, but your solution still need the caller kown it.

Comment: This does not appear to be a `sequelize.transaction` option. Current (5.x) options are `type`, `isolationLevel`, `deferrable`, `logging`, and `autoCallback`. The option `transaction` is not specified. A PR is needed for sequelize, as this is an undocumented option: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10840

Answer (score 5):

If you use [CLS](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/transactions/#automatically-pass-transactions-to-all-queries), a very simple helper function will do the work.

```js
const cls = require('continuation-local-storage');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const NAMESPACE = 'your-namespace';

// Use CLS for Sequelize
Sequelize.cls = cls.createNamespace(NAMESPACE);
const sequelize = new Sequelize(...);

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * THE MAGIC: Create a transaction wrapper
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

function transaction(task) {
  return cls.getNamespace(NAMESPACE).get('transaction') ? task() : sequelize.transaction(task);
};

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Your code below
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

function addUser(userName, password) {
  return transaction(function() {
    return AccountModel
      .create(...)
      .then(() => UserModel.create(...));
  });
}

function addTeam() {
  return transaction(function() {
    return TeamModel
      .create(...)
      .then(() => addUser(...));
  });
}
```

Comment: There is a discussion in v5.x to remove cls: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10819

Comment: @coler-j The `cls-hooked` is now considered a valid option, and the cls support is no longer considered to be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an accepted answer, below answer refers to a chain of commands (not necessarily nested) we may want to execute in the same transaction, using async-await:

```
try{
      // create a transaction
      let transaction = await sequelize.transaction();
      // "parent" insertion, id is auto increment, so we will need the id of inserted data
      let record = await Parent_Record.create({ 
        data_1: req.params.data1,
        data_2: req.params.data2,
        ....
        }, {transaction});
        //the array contains data depending upon the id of inserted parent transaction 
        for ( x  in dataForChildTable) {
          result = await Child_Record.create({
          id: record.id, //same transaction so we can use record.id of parent
          .....
          other_data: dataForChildTable[x].otherData}, {transaction});
      }
      //commit the transaction
      await transaction.commit();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
```

Comment: How is this a nested transaction. I only see 1 transaction...

Comment: @Glen you are right, i may misinterpreted the question a bit. I modified the answer so it is more clear which issue it addresses. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [zb-sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zb-sequelize) which adds transactional decorators.

```
import { Transactional, Tx } from 'zb-sequelize';

@Transactional
function addUser(user, password, @Tx transaction) {
  // no need to create, commit or rollback a transaction.
}
```

You do need to initialize it with your `sequelize` instance.

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import { initSequelizeResolver } from 'zb-sequelize';

// you already have this somewhere.
const sequelize = new Sequelize(options);

// you need to add this:
initSequelizeResolver((args) => sequelize);
```